# Javascript treating int as string mid formula

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a rather simple javascipt formula:

```
Math.round(minMax[0] + ((minMax[1] - minMax[0]) / 2));
```

Value of minMax[0] is 1 and minMax[1] is 5

But for some reason i get the result **12** out of this. where i was expecting **3**, now my guess is that it calculates `((minMax[1] - minMax[0]) / 2)` to 2 but then adds them together as a string with the result of "1"+"2" = 12

What can i do to make javascript see this as numbers?

Update:
if i change the formula to the following then it workes, but is ugly as hell

```
index = Math.round(parseInt(minMax[0]) + ((parseInt(minMax[1]) - parseInt(minMax[0])) / 2));
```

Update 2: How min max is found, this is in Typescript

```
private getMinMaxIndex(parentIds: number[]): number[] {
            var minIndex = 99999999;
            var maxIndex = -1;

            for (var k in parentIds) {
                var index = this.getIndexOf(parentIds[k]);
                if (index > maxIndex) maxIndex = index;
                if (index < minIndex) minIndex = index;
            }
            return [minIndex, maxIndex];
        }
...
var minMax = this.getMinMaxIndex(limitedParents);
index = Math.round(parseInt(minMax[0]) + ((parseInt(minMax[1]) - parseInt(minMax[0])) / 2));
```

Update 3:

```
private getIndexOf(id: number) {
    var nodes: INode[] = this.nodes.Get();
    for (var i in nodes) {
        if (nodes[i].GetId() == id)
            return i;
    }

    console.log("Unable to find parent index, for node id: " + id + " in swimlane " + this.Name + ", this should not happen and will break.");
    console.log(nodes);
    return null;
}
export interface INode{
    GetId(): number;
    ...
}

export class SubmissionNode implements INode {

    ...

    constructor(data: DiagramInputObject) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public GetId(): number {
        return this.data.Id;
    }
}

export interface DiagramInputObject {
    Id: number;
    ...
}

Finally the DiagramInputObject in question that is how it is parsed into the code
{
    Id: 1014, 
    UserId: 1, 
    Type: 0, 
    SwimLaneId: null, 
    SwimLaneName: null, 
    Submitted: new Date("3/9/2014 8:56:00 PM"), 
    ParentId: 9, 
    MergeId: null, 
    Exportable: false, 
    TypeData: "null", 
}
```

Comment: I just pasted your code into Chrome's console and the result is 3.

Comment: In Firefox works as expected, too. Where are you executing this?

Comment: The code you posted does not work the way you say it does.  Is this **really** the code that's causing you problems?

Comment: There's a strong indicator that the array contains strings, and doesn't really look like what you've posted here.

Comment: No i have added var minMax = [1, 5]; to show the value of the variables.

Comment: And if you do `console.log( typeof minMax[0] )` what do you get

Comment: @DoomStone well try that code in your browser console. It will not do what you say it does.

Comment: @adeneo the code is hidden with alot of classes so i will not be able to do that.

Comment: See the new update, that i sho i make the minMax

Comment: Woot, you're able to add parseInt, but not a console.log ?

Comment: So what does `.getIndexOf()` do?  Look, you really just need to debug your code. Something that you *think* is returning a number is actually returning a string.

Comment: @adeneo minMax[0]: string minMax[1]: string

Comment: Also **do not use `for ... in` loops for arrays.** *edit* so there you go, the array values are not numbers.

Comment: @DoomStone use `for (var i = 0; i < array.length; ++i)` or the `.forEach()` array method. Using `for ... in` is fraught with peril.

Comment: @Pointy this is a huge javascript library i have written, but it all is written in typescript and the value is always a number and never a string.

Comment: @DoomStone didn't your `console.log()` just tell you that it was a string?  The problem probably lies in your `getIndexOf()` function.

Comment: If the console says it's a string, it's a string.

Comment: @adeneo I am well aware of that, my question is to why this happens.

Comment: See Update 3 for full history of the variable

Answer (score -2, accepted):

As other people have pointed out, and i was already aware of, is that the variable is not a integer.
I was using typescript so i did not exepect this problem, to solve it have i added parseInt around the numbers to ensure it is an integer.

The wierd thing is that `((minMax[1] - minMax[0]) / 2)` is calculated as a number, but where `minMax[0] + ((minMax[1] - minMax[0]) / 2)` is not. I can only guess that the /2 forces javascript to view the varaibles as integers, just wired that this dose not extend to `minMax[0] +`.

Answer (score 2):

```
private getIndexOf(id: number) {
    var nodes: INode[] = this.nodes.Get();
    for (var i in nodes) { // <---- PROBLEM HERE
        if (nodes[i].GetId() == id)
            return i;
    }

    console.log("Unable to find parent index, for node id: " + id + " in swimlane " + this.Name + ", this should not happen and will break.");
    console.log(nodes);
    return null;
}
```

Remember that in JavaScript, *all* (**all!**)  array indexes are actually strings. A `for in` loop enumerates all of the keys of an object, and all keys of an object are strings. `getIndexOf`, then, returns a string.

You should just use a standard length-based `for` loop:

```
for(var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
    /* same loop body */
}
```

Comment: This is a nice tip, but sadly not the awnser to the question.